# PowerShell, Cannot read data file

Tags: powershell, powershell-v6.0

I have a PowerShell script that reads a `register.psd1` file with contents as below.

```
@{
    # Building Zig compiler
    zig = @{
        name = "zig"
        path = ./python/buildzig.py
        language = "Python"
        os = "all" 
    }

    # Building Windows Terminal for Windows 10.
    windowsterminal = @{
        name = "WindowsTerminal"
        path = ./powershell/msterminal.ps1
        language = "Python"
        os = "windows"  
    }
}
```

I read the file using the following command.

```
Import-PowerShellDataFile -Path register.psd1
```

After running the script I get the following error message.

```
Import-PowerShellDataFile : Cannot generate a PowerShell object for a ScriptBlock evaluating dynamic expressions.
```

What am I doing wrong and what is the possible solution?

Comment: Enclose the paths in double quotes. `"./python/buildzig.py"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`*.psd1` files contain PowerShell *[hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-6) literals*** and therefore require the **same syntax as when defining such literals *in code***:

Therefore, if you want to create an entry with key `path` that contains the *string literal* `./python/buildzig.py` (or `./powershell/msterminal.ps1`), you must *quote* it - either form is OK here:

- `path = '.\powershell\msterminal.ps1'`
- `path = ".\powershell\msterminal.ps1"`

However, given that in the context of a `*.psd1` file you're virtually limited to *literal* values, use of `'...'` (single quotes) makes more sense (see [about_Quoting_Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules)).

---

As for **what you tried**:

A hashtable entry such as  `path = ./python/buildzig.py` attempts to create an entry with key `path` and the value that is the result of *executing* file `./python/buildzig.py`, because - **in the absence of *quoting* - the token is interpreted as a *command*** (see [about_Parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing) to learn about how PowerShell parses commands and expressions).

The - unfortunately vague - error message you saw (`Cannot generate a PowerShell object for a ScriptBlock evaluating dynamic expressions.`), stems from the fact that **for security reasons, executing commands isn't permitted in `*.psd1` files**, which are (mostly<sup>[1]</sup>) limited to defining *literal* values.

---

<sup>[1] You can use the following "variables", which in effect are *constants*: `$true`, `$false`, `$null`. Additionally, depending on the purpose of the `*.psd1` file, a select few additional automatic variables are permitted: `$PSCulture` and `$PSUICulture`, except in files to be read by `Import-PowerShellDataFile`, and, additionally, `$PSScriptRoot`, `$PSEdition`, and `$EnabledExperimentalFeatures` in *module manifests* - see [about_Language_Modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_language_modes).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I have just added ' ' for the path parameters as following after that the error was gone. hope this is the output you wanted.

```
path = '.\powershell\msterminal.ps1'
```